# react-native-webview android issue: Found interface com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher, but class was expected

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native-webview for my react native app which has the rn version 0.64.4,
But I cannot open screen when we have a web view in it, the app get crash immediately. this is only happening on the android. Then I open up the android project via android studio, then I could see the below error on the log. How can I fix this issue?

Error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xapp, PID: 21712
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher' appears in /data/app/~~qPom7HPfdYNLFEMUio836A==/com.verime-gQSY9JQLtB6GGgsqfvIrFg==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
        at com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewManager.dispatchEvent(RNCWebViewManager.java:168)
        at com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewManager$RNCWebChromeClient.onProgressChanged(RNCWebViewManager.java:1153)
        at la.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-530410534:278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "xapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "np": "np --no-publish",
    "postversion": "react-native-version",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
    "@woonivers/react-native-document-scanner": "^2.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "npm": "^7.20.5",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.10.0",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.4",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.30.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.0.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^5.0.3",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.21.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-image-to-pdf": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-image-tools-wm": "^1.5.8",
    "react-native-invoke-app": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-jitsi-meet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-pdf-lib": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-perspective-image-cropper": "git+https://github.com/kmwi/react-native-perspective-image-cropper.git",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-rectangle-scanner": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "git+https://github.com/expo/react-native-svg.git",
    "react-native-tooltips": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-user-avatar": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-virtual-keyboard": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.18.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.13",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "np": "^7.6.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-version": "^4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.3",
    "reactotron-redux-saga": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar case here, the libraries involved are invertase/react-native-apple-authentication and react-native-webview. They suddenly started crashing due to a Kotlin version difference, after correcting them, react-native-reanimated started giving a similar error as yours, but instead of expecting a class, it expects interface, the other way around.

Found class com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher, but interface was expected.
at com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager.(NodesManager.java:116)

UPDATE: I just resolved my problem, it was due to a library trying to use a newer version of react native, and I ended upgrading my project to RN 64.

Since RN 64, the EventDispatcher.java file in the react-native project changed a lot, from class in 63.5 to a interface in 64. Your issue could be that a library is trying to use older RN version and is expecting a class, but your RN version already works with Interface regarding that file.

Hope it helps you, good luck!